# Joomla article text truncating in category list

Tags: joomla

I am having an issue with Joomla whereas the text for articles being displayed in a category blog or category list is being cut off.
I would like to show articles on a page with all the text being shown and not truncated.

Here is a picture of the issue. As you can see the first article is being truncated whereas the second and third are fine as they are shorter than length.

[image]

I have tried amending the 'read-more' settings, changed the intro text size and several other options and just can't seem to sort this issue. I have also looked in the default templates for the content articles to change the size manualy but can't see where I can do this.

Is anybody able to help with this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Click Content->Categories
- Click Options (on Categories Page)
- Click on the Blog/Featured Layouts
- Change the "# Leading Articles" count from 1 to 10 or higher
- Change the "# Intro Articles" count to 0